# Kotlin Check and access a class from List<Any>

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, casting, any

How can you check and access adViewClass from the array of Any?

```
val adViewClass = AddViewClass(name = "an instance")
val elements = listOf("trevor", "john", adViewClass, "0goo")
```

How to get that `adViewClass` from list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple [elementAt](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-elements.html) to get class

```
elements.elementAt(2)
```

> `elementAt()` is useful for collections that do not provide indexed access, or are not statically known to provide one. In case of List, it's more idiomatic to use indexed access operator (get() or []).

and check class using [is](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)

```
if (obj is AdViewClass) {
```

> We can check whether an object conforms to a given type at runtime by using the is operator

Answer (score 4):

You can get **all instances of a specific class** that are in a list using the `filterIsInstance(Class<>)`

```
val elements: List<Any> = listOf<Any>("trevor", "john", AdViewClass, "0goo")
val listOfAdViewClass = elements.filterIsInstance(AdViewClass::class.java)
```

The filtered list will contain all instances of that class in the list.